# Print lines after uniq with column condition

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk, uniq

I have a file with following contents in a file

```
192.168.168.23 pg.something
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing
15.123.96.12 l.everything
15.151.15.3 f.something
15.151.15.3 pg.something
64.196.12.34 pg.nothing
15.123.96.12 l.everything
181.168.56.13 pg.nothing
192.168.168.23 pg.something
192.168.168.23 l.everything
192.12.56.152 l.everything
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing
64.196.12.34 pg.nothing
64.196.12.34 pg.something
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing
64.196.12.34 l.everything
```

I am trying to find out no of hits by each IP to each user sorted by IP.

I tried this.

```
for i in `cat test_file |awk '{print $1}'|sort |uniq -c |sort -rn |awk '{print $2}'`; do grep $i test_file;done |uniq -c |awk '{print $2,$3,$1}'
```

and got

```
64.196.12.34 pg.nothing 2
64.196.12.34 pg.something 1
64.196.12.34 l.everything 1
192.168.168.23 pg.something 2
192.168.168.23 l.everything 1
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing 3
15.151.15.3 f.something 1
15.151.15.3 pg.something 1
15.123.96.12 l.everything 2
192.12.56.152 l.everything 1
181.168.56.13 pg.nothing 1
```

This output is fine. But I am wondering if there is a way to modify this output to look like this...

```
64.196.12.34 pg.nothing 2
             pg.something 1
             l.everything 1
192.168.168.23 pg.something 2
               l.everything 1
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing 3
15.151.15.3 f.something 1
            pg.something 1
15.123.96.12 l.everything 2
192.12.56.152 l.everything 1
181.168.56.13 pg.nothing 1
```

That is remove only the duplicate IPs...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify you last awk command with :

```
awk '{if ($2!=a) {print $2"\t"$3"\t"$1} else {print "\t\t"$3"\t"$1}}{a=$2}'
```

Which gives :

```
64.196.12.34    pg.nothing      2
                pg.something    1
                l.everything    1
192.168.168.23  pg.something    2
                l.everything    1
181.135.56.13   pg.nothing      3
15.151.15.3     f.something     1
                pg.something    1
15.123.96.12    l.everything    2
192.12.56.152   l.everything    1
181.168.56.13   pg.nothing      1
```

Comment: thanks. It works. Exactly what I needed. Tweaked it a bit.
awk '{if ($2!=a) {print $2"\t"$3"\t"$1} else {print "\t\t"$3"\t"$1}}{a=$2}'.

Comment: no pb! Just accept the answer ! (and thanks for the "=", i'll edit with your version)

Answer (score 0):

This is something that calculates from scratch:

```
awk '
     {a[$1,$2]++; b[$1]; c[$2]}
     END{for (i in b) {for (j in c) if (a[i,j]) print i,j,a[i,j]}}
    ' file | awk '
                  $1==prev {print FS $2 FS $3; next} {prev=$1; print}
                 '
```

#### First part does the count:

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]++; b[$1]; c[$2]} END{for (i in b) {for (j in c) if (a[i,j]) print i,j,a[i,j]}}' a 
192.168.168.23 pg.something 2
192.168.168.23 l.everything 1
192.12.56.152 l.everything 1
64.196.12.34 pg.nothing 2
64.196.12.34 pg.something 1
64.196.12.34 l.everything 1
15.151.15.3 f.something 1
15.151.15.3 pg.something 1
15.123.96.12 l.everything 2
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing 3
181.168.56.13 pg.nothing 1
```

#### Explanation

- `{a[$1,$2]++; b[$1]; c[$2]}` keep track of all the lines combinations: `a` stores the 1st + 2nd field, `b` the 1st and `c` the 2nd.
- `END{for (i in b) {for (j in c) if (a[i,j]) print i,j,a[i,j]}}` keeps looping through 1st and 2nd field, printing only those that have a matching.

#### And from that it does the grouping:

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]++; b[$1]; c[$2]} END{for (i in b) {for (j in c) if (a[i,j]) print i,j,a[i,j]}}' a | awk '$1==prev {print FS $2 FS $3; next} {prev=$1; print}'
192.168.168.23 pg.something 2
 l.everything 1
192.12.56.152 l.everything 1
64.196.12.34 pg.nothing 2
 pg.something 1
 l.everything 1
15.151.15.3 f.something 1
 pg.something 1
15.123.96.12 l.everything 2
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing 3
181.168.56.13 pg.nothing 1
```

#### Explanation

- `'$1==prev {print FS $2 FS $3; next}` in case the previous line had the same 1st field, do  print just from the 2nd field.
- `{prev=$1; print}'` otherwise, print normally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl version solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($ip, $dom) = split;
    $data{$ip}->{$dom}++;
}

while(my ($ip, $doms) = each %data) {
    print "$ip\t";
    my ($dom, $cnt) = each %$doms;
    print "$dom $cnt\n";
    while (($dom, $cnt) = each %$doms) {
        print "\t\t$dom $cnt\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
192.168.168.23 pg.something
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing
15.123.96.12 l.everything
15.151.15.3 f.something
15.151.15.3 pg.something
64.196.12.34 pg.nothing
15.123.96.12 l.everything
181.168.56.13 pg.nothing
192.168.168.23 pg.something
192.168.168.23 l.everything
192.12.56.152 l.everything
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing
64.196.12.34 pg.nothing
64.196.12.34 pg.something
181.135.56.13 pg.nothing
64.196.12.34 l.everything
```

And its result:

```
192.12.56.152   l.everything 1

15.151.15.3     pg.something 1
                f.something 1

64.196.12.34    pg.nothing 2
                pg.something 1
                l.everything 1

181.168.56.13   pg.nothing 1

15.123.96.12    l.everything 2

192.168.168.23  pg.something 2
                l.everything 1

181.135.56.13   pg.nothing 3
```

The result does not aligned very nicely, but it should be quite easy to adjust it to give exactly the same alignment as in the question.

And here is the adapted version:

```
while(my ($ip, $doms) = each %data) {
    print "$ip ";
    my ($dom, $cnt) = each %$doms;
    print "$dom $cnt\n";
    my $prefix = ' ' x (length $ip);
    while (($dom, $cnt) = each %$doms) {
        print "$prefix $dom $cnt\n";
    }
}
```